# Android/ Java closure onClick problem?

Tags: java, android, reference, closures

Here is basically my code:

```
private Dialog mDialog;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

... 

private void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    enabltBTButton = getMyButton();
    enableBtButton.setOnClickListener(this.enableBT);
    ...
}

...

public View.OnClickListener enableBT = (new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mDialog.hide();
        mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
        Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Bluetooth enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
});
```

The problem: when I click the button nothing happens! I am positive that `enableBTButton` is referring to the correct object, but my guess is that this has something to do with my referencing `mDialog` and `mBluetoothAdapter,` both of which are declared outside of the inner `onClick` function.

What is an alternative solution to this?

Comment: Do you see that toast on tapping the button ?

Comment: I suggest you put some calls to Log.d() in your listener and check logcat output to be sure that you are really getting into the listener or not.

Comment: I'd like to see how `getMyButton` is defined; also how (and where) `mDialog` and `mBluetoothAdapter` are initialized. And as codeboy2k suggested, make a call to Log.d() as the very first line in the listener, to verify that you're really not getting there at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather then keep fumbling with what I had, I decided that to use an AlertDialog, which seems to get the job done quite well. Thank you everyone for your solutions.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Bluetooth is not enabled...")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Enable it!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    ...
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Leave it!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth still disabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            AlertDialog mAlert = builder.create();
            mAlert.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the pasted code you have:

```
private void onCreate()
```

but it should be:

```
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

If it really is a "private onCreate()" in your code, then it won't get called by the framework because it doesn't override Activity.onCreate(Bundle), which means the onClickListener is not set up for your button either.

Comment: My code is not exact, I also have this in my actual code, and the ellipsis are to supplement all of the usual stuff like `setContentView`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are calling a function `setOnClickEventListener`, but you should be calling `setOnClickListener`. Is `setOnClickEventListener` a function you wrote?

(By the way, you can test your guess about referencing mDialog and/or mBluetoothAdapter by commenting out those lines. I don't think that's the problem.)

Comment: Actually I was calling `setOnClickListener` in my code, I'm not sure where the Event came from. I compiled it again to make sure, nothing changed. As for commenting mDialog and mBluetoohAdapter, that is what I did and I got a fatal NullException.

Comment: I meant to comment out the calls to `mDialog.hide()` and `mBluetoothAdapter.enable()` in the click handler. That will show that using those variables have nothing to do with the listener not being called. Are you sure that `getMyButton()` is returning the correct Button object (the one corresponding to the button you are clicking)?